# How do I erase a CD/DVD-R

Tags: dvd, cd, brasero

For some reason, the Basero GUI isn't detecting my CD when I try to use the blanking option there. I tried various terminal commands, none of them worked. If anyone could help me out here, I would really appreciate it.

Here is there error I get when using these commands: "umount /dev/cdrom" and "cdrecord dev=/dev/cdrom blank=fast"

```
wodim: Cannot blank disk, aborting.
wodim: Some drives do not support all blank types.
wodim: Try again with wodim blank=all.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have finalized your CD/DVD-R isn't possible erase it.

You can erase CD/DVD-**RW** types.